# How do SSDs map Bytes to TLCs?

Tags: hard-drive, ssd, storage

- SLC = 1 bit  per cell
- MLC = 2 bits per cell
- TLC = 3 bits per cell

I would guess that SSDs with MLC NAND need 4 cells for each Byte.
How is this done on TLC NAND? A Byte gets extended to 9 bits and is stored in 3 cells?

Comment: The keyword here is "erase block". I'm currently away from my PC, so I cannot research a complete answer though, sorry.

Comment: You cannot read (or write) just one byte from NAND flash; it's a ***block*** (not a character) device. (Look at the available commands that a NAND chip can perform, e.g. read page, instead of just the low-level cell structure.) So it doesn't matter if 3 doesn't divide into 8 without a remainder.  Three bytes would span eight TLC cells.

Comment: Doesn't really matter how the bits are mapped to cells.  The (contents of the) selected NAND page has to be copied into (or from) the page register before any data is read (or written) by the NAND chip.  Look at Figure 3 of https://www.micron.com/~/media/documents/products/technical-note/nand-flash/tn2919_nand_101.pdf  The mapping of cells to bytes is under full control of this internal register interface.

Comment: Remember that error-correcting codes will add extra bits.